# Facebook presentations

Tags: facebook

Where can I find all presentations by facebook on their technologies and architecture ? Any recommendations for some impressive presentations by facebook, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find out all metrics and technical details how they are achieved. http://highscalability.com/blog/category/facebook

Answer (score 0):

Most of these are posted to the [Facebook Engineering](http://www.facebook.com/Engineering) Blog. Specifically the [Engineering videos](http://www.facebook.com/Engineering/videos) page.